# Mithril component don't return anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, mithril.js

can you help with Mithril? Again? :)

In this component I want to show some data, but m() doesn't show anything, however data is't empty.
Thank you very much

```
var default_panel_component = {
    controller: function(args) {
        return {
            'data': args.data //Object {name1: "data1", name2: "data2", name3: "data3"}
        }
    },
    view: function(ctrl) {
        return m("table", [
            $.each(ctrl.data, function (key, value) {
                console.log(key), //key1
                console.log(value), //data1
                console.log(typeof value), //string
                m("td", value)
            })
        ])
    }
};
```

Comment: `m` should either return an object or throw an error. In this case it should definitely return an object. It doesn't look like there's enough information here to work out what's going wrong for you. Maybe try asking on [the Mithril chatroom](https://gitter.im/lhorie/mithril.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you are using `$.each` to build the children of the `m('table')` call, but `each` will just be executed on every object, not returning anything. So, essentially, you are left with an empty table.

What you need is `[$.map][1]`, that translates all items in an array or object to a new array of items. With that you will be returning a `m('td')` element for each property on `ctrl.data`.

You can see it working [on this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/patillades/1k7pt9wh/). I also set the tds as children of a table row, so take that into account if you need to generate several rows.

Comment: Thank you very much, I got it

Comment: Hi @ConflictBoy I'm glad it helped. Please consider [accepting this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.